# Hedge Effectiveness

Tags: derivatives, swaps, hedging

I am trying to prove the hedge effectiveness of a SWAP, I know that a regression needs to be done between the hedged item (Loan) and the hedging instrument (SWAP), but I don't know which values should I take in order to do the regression.

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of swap - interest rate swap, credit default swaps, total return swap, some other? Which risks are yiu hedging? Do you mark the asset to market daily? Does the loan allow prepayments? Are you able to calculate the asset's intetest rate risk?

Comment: It's an interest rate swap. Hedging the variable rate of the payments of a loan. The loan allows prepayments.

Comment: Curiouser.. so the loan pays you SOFR + fixed spread, are you aiming to change that to you receiving fixed, using a swap where you pay SOFR and receive fixed, which would actually _increase_ your interest rate risk?